# Does Isa. 46:10 imply that in God's sovereignty he created everything that happens in time at the beginning of creation?

Tags: hebrew, isaiah, attributes-of-god

```
   מַגִּ֤יד מֵֽרֵאשִׁית֙ אַחֲרִ֔ית 
   וּמִקֶּ֖דֶם אֲשֶׁ֣ר לֹא־נַעֲשׂ֑וּ 
   אֹמֵר֙ עֲצָתִ֣י תָק֔וּם 
   וְכָל־חֶפְצִ֖י אֶעֱשֶֽׂה׃ 
             (Isa. 46:10, MT)
```

מֵֽרֵאשִׁית֙ - from the beginning -- בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית -- in the beginning (Gen. 1:1)

וּמִקֶּ֖דֶם - and from ancient times -- מִקֶּ֗דֶם -- from everlasting (Hab. 1:12)

```
   declaring the end from the beginning 
  and from ancient times things not yet done, 
              saying, ‘My counsel shall stand, 
  and I will accomplish all my purpose,’ 
              (Isa. 46:10, ESV)

           Declaring the end from the beginning,
     And from ancient times things which have not been done,
     Saying, ‘My purpose will be established,
     And I will accomplish all My good pleasure’;
                        (Isa. 46:10, NASB)

  I foretell the end from the beginning, 
  And from the start, things that had not occurred. 
  I say: My plan shall be fulfilled; 
  I will do all I have purposed. 
                  (Isa. 46:10, JPS Tanakh)
```

Note the passage:

```
  By the word of the LORD the heavens were made, 
     by the breath of His mouth, all their host. 
  He heaps up the ocean waters like a mound, 
     stores the deep in vaults. 

  Let all the earth fear the LORD; 
     let all the inhabitants of the world dread Him. 
  For He spoke, and it was; 
     He commanded, and it endured. 
            (Psalm 33:6–9, JPS Torah)
```

Also consider Isa. 55:8-11

```
  For My plans are not your plans, 
  Nor are My ways your ways 
      —declares the LORD. 
  But as the heavens are high above the earth, 
  So are My ways high above your ways 
  And My plans above your plans. 
  For as the rain or snow drops from heaven 
  And returns not there, 
  But soaks the earth 
  And makes it bring forth vegetation, 
  Yielding seed for sowing and bread for eating, 
  So is the word that issues from My mouth: 
  It does not come back to Me unfulfilled, 
  But performs what I purpose, 
  Achieves what I sent it to do. 
         (Is 55:8–11, JPS Tanakh)
```

While Isa. 46:10 does not specifically reference the beginning of time and end of time, it implies God's attributes are such that he created the totality of time as well as matter at creation.

Comment: I am struggling to understand what question you are asking here.  Isa 46:10 is discussing God's eternal purpose and omniscience and does not mention His creation.  The same is true of Isa 55:8-11.

Comment: @Dottard: Is it clearer now?

Comment: I am not sure whether you are asking a cosmological question (Did time and space begin together when created by God? or, Did God create time before or during creation week? etc) or a theological question of some other kind.

Comment: Further, as you would well know, "beginning" is not absolute but has a reference to the things/object which it describes - beginning in Gen 1:1 describes the beginning of this world, not necessarily the beginning of time.

Comment: @Dottard: I'm asking a theological question.  A cosmological question such as this involves modern physics and is beyond the scope of this hermeneutics.  It's a question about God's sovereignty, not a question of human free will.

Comment: Then I think that these verses simply attempt to put in human language what is almost inexpressible - God's absolute sovereignty, His omniscience, and absolute fore-knowledge.  All this is beyond human understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isa. 46:

> 10a declaring the end from the beginning
> and from ancient times things not yet done,

This is an incredible statement. Only God can say it truthfully in the absolute sense. It shows the speaker of a being standing outside of the space-time dimensions. He saw the totality of the 4-dimensional space-time sequence.

OP: While Isa. 46:10 does not specifically reference the beginning of time and end of time, it implies God's attributes are such that he created the totality of time as well as matter at creation.

I think so. According to General Relativity, you cannot even separate space from time. Both are affected simultaneously by gravity. Different people in different gravitational fields will experience the passage of time differently.
When you look up to a star at night, you are looking far away into space and back in time.
If God has created space, then according to Relativity, God must have created time as well.
Moreover, God has seen the entire sequence of events being played out in time.

Answer (score 3):

While Isa. 46:10 does not specifically reference the beginning of time and end of time, it implies God's attributes are such that he created the totality of time as well as matter at creation.

You are so right that God did create time as part of creation.

God did make periods of time called ages. He made them through His Son.

Here are some scriptures concerning the eons or ages that are mentioned in scripture.

aiónios: agelong,
Original Word: αἰώνιος, ία, ιον

Usage: age-long, and therefore: partaking of the character of that which lasts for an age, as contrasted with that which is brief and fleeting.

The answer eons or ages have a beginning.

> in His Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, and through whom He made the ages, Hebrews 1:2

There is wisdom but it's not in this age.

> And wisdom we speak among the perfect, and wisdom not of this age, nor of the rulers of this age—of those becoming useless,  1Corinthians 2:7

There was a time before the eons or ages.

> he gave us in Christ Jesus before the ages began,2 Timothy
> 1:9

Ages have an end.

> “Tell us, when will these things be, and what will be the sign of your coming and of the end of the age?”Matthew 24:3

Something was hid from the eons.

> the mystery having been
> hidden from the ages and from the generations, but now having been manifested to His saints,  Colossians1:26

> Romans 16:25
> Now to Him who is able to strengthen you by my gospel and by the proclamation of Jesus Christ, according to the revelation of the mystery concealed for ages past

> and to illuminate for everyone the stewardship of this mystery, which for ages past was kept hidden in God, who created all things. Ephesians 3:9

> 34Jesus answered, “The sons of this age marry and are given in marriage.  Luke 20:34

There are eons to come.

> And God raised us up with Christ and seated us with Him in the heavenly realms in Christ Jesus, 7in order that in the coming ages He might display the surpassing riches of His grace, demonstrated by His kindness to us in Christ Jesus.  Ephesians 2:6-7

There is a purpose of the eons.

> the least of all the holy ones—was given this grace, among the nations to proclaim good news—the untraceable riches of the Christ, 9and to cause all to see what [is] the fellowship of the secret that has been hid from the ages in God, who created all things by Jesus Christ, 10that there might be made known now to the principalities and the authorities in the heavenly [places], through the Assembly, the manifold wisdom of God,

> according to a purpose of the ages, which He made in Christ Jesus our Lord,  Ephesians 3:8-11

> having made known to us the secret of His will, according to His good pleasure, that He purposed in Himself, 10in regard to the dispensation of the fulness of the times, to bring into one the whole in the Christ, both the things in the heavens, and the things upon the earth — in him; 11in whom also we did obtain an inheritance, being foreordained according to the purpose of Him who the all things is working according to the counsel of His will, Ephesians 1:9-11

> The Son is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn over all creation. 16For in Him all things were created, things in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities. All things were created through Him and for Him.
> 17He is before all things, and in Him all things hold together. 18And He is the head of the body, the church; He is the beginning and firstborn from among the dead, so that in all things He may have preeminence. 19For God was pleased to have all His fullness dwell in Him, 20and through Him to reconcile to Himself all things, whether things on earth or things in heaven, by making peace through the blood of His cross.  Colossians 1:15-20

God has always been, He is eternal.  He did create time and broke it up in ages and even within those ages there's time or eras, seasons..

Comment: Given that there could be no start to a material universe without time-space, then God's creation of the universe must have had the creation of time at that very instant. For space (and matter within it) to expand and develop requires time. As this universe is expanding, God must have created time. Interestingly, 'eternity' is a dimension of the spirit realm, as stated in the Bible. Can you expand your opening sentence to make more of a case for your claim, even if you disagree with my points?

Comment: Anne, appreciate your comment.  "we speak among the perfect, and wisdom not of this age, nor of the rulers of this age — of those becoming useless, but we speak the hidden wisdom of God in a secret, that God foreordained before the ages to our glory, which no one of the rulers of this age did know,"
YLT 1 Co.2:6-8 The word aión: #165 is a space of time, an age.  It's where we get the word eon. eon An indefinitely long period of time; an age.
The longest division of geologic time, containing two or more eras.  A long space of time; either indefinite or limited to the duration of something,